# Date part function in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a sample data set below:

```
Date
01/01/2010
01/02/2010
01/03/2010
```

Running the query below gives:

```
SELECT
   DATEPART (MONTH, Date)  AS MONTH
FROM MYTABLE
```

OUTPUT:

```
MONTH
1
```

I would like to the output as `mm/dd/yyyy` format as below.

```
MONTH
01/01/2010
```

Could someone please look into it?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to truncate date to a month, you might use:

```
select dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Put your date column instead of getdate().

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the latest SQL Server 2012, you can use [`datefromparts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) function to make a "first of the month" date, like this:

```
SELECT
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date), 1) AS FIRST_OF_THE_MONTH
FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: That's a great new function - but only available in SQL Server **2012** (which not a lot of folks will already have and use)

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the correction - I mentioned that in the answer, although I agree that at this point it is likely to be useless. I did not realize that this function is *that* new.

Comment: @ marc_s - That is correct. I am using SQL server 2005. So it gives me error. Thanks Marc_s and Das.